# "hashchange" doesn't fire on url change

Tags: jquery, javascript, url

Hi I am building this website: http://www.freiheitmedia.com/en/. It is build with the Themify Ultra theme.

**My goal is to get rid of the *#something* part in the url when scrolling or clicking on a link.**

I need to do it with JavaScript/jQuery because there is no theme based solution and the support staff can't help me.

I already tested and know that the following code replaces the url as I want:

```
history.replaceState("",document.title,window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

Now, the problem is that **I seemingly can't get the "hashchange" event to fire.** I am putting the following code in the footer and the alert statement is not reached in both cases:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){
        alert("hiii");
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){
        alert("hiii");
    }, false);
</script>
```

I suspect that the hashchange event might be prevented by the theme's settings but it's just a guess.

**Do you guys have any idea why "hashchange" doesn't fire?**

Comment: *"My goal is to get rid of the #something part in the url when scrolling or clicking on a link."* Don't; this is pointless and annoying.

Comment: @ryan Well, the client wants this. Can you elaborate what you mean by pointless and annoying? As in, what are the downsides of doing this, e.g. for UX?